# Comparison of Pojo class properties

Tags: java

I have a class containing two properties:

```
public class player{
    public player(String playerName,int points){
        this.playerName=playerName;
        this.points=points;
    }
    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }
    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
    private String playerName;
    private int points;
}
```

I have arrayList class contains collection of palyer objects.

```
List palyers=new ArrayList();
players.add(new player("mike",2));
players.add(new player("steve",3));
players.add(new player("jhon",7));
players.add(new player("harry",5);
```

Here my question is how to display player names with  smallest points difference.

Output:

```
Based on the example code i written:

Mike and steve is the output

THis way comparison should happen:

mike to steve --> 1

mike to jhon--->5

mike to harry-->3

steve to mike -->1
steve to jhon--->5
steve to harry--->3

jhon to mike-->5
jhon to steve-->4
jhon to harry--->2

harry to mike -->3

harry to steve-->2

harry to jhon -->2

Based on above comparison mike and steve should display
```

Any java API to compare the properties?

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for all your answers,But here i dont need sorting order of points.I want a final result to display the players with smallest difference in their points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know the pair of players whose score has the smallest difference?
I don't think there's an API function for that, although there might be something in the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

Otherwise you'll have to use a nested loop.

```
int res1 = -1, res2 = -1;

int maxDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for ( int i = 0; i < players.size( ); i++ )
{
    for ( int j = i + 1; j < players.size() ; j++ )
    {
        int diff = Math.abs( players.get(i).getPoints( ) - players.get(j).getPoints( ) );
        if ( diff < maxDiff )
        {
            maxDiff = diff;
            res1 = i;
            res2 = j;
        }           
    }
}
System.out.println(players.get(res1).getPlayerName( ) + " and " + players.get(res2).getPlayerName( ));
```

Obviously, this code needs some work; for example, if two pairs of players have the same difference between them, only the latest pair processed will be reported. You may also want to re-work this piece of code to remove the default values (Note how the `System.out.println` will crash if your List contains 0 players, for example). I leave these for you to solve. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Using [anonymous inner class](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/anonymous_innerclassestutorial.shtml), [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Collections.sort()](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/):

```
    Collections.sort(palyers, new Comparator(){
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
            player p1 = (player) o1;
            player p2 = (player) o2;

            return p1.getPoints().compareTo(p2.getPoints());
            }
        });.
```

Comment: +1: i prefer your method of having the comparison external to the class since this is more flexible.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your answers,But here i dont need sorting order of points.I want a final result to display the players with smallest difference in their points

Answer (score 1):

Write a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use it to sort the `List` by points.  You're just comparing `Player` instances.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for all your answers,But here i dont need sorting order of points.I want a final result to display the players with smallest difference in their points

Comment: @Raju Komaturi You can customize the Comparator to sort by point differences, not just points.

Comment: @ Eric Hydrick :I edited my question,Please find the ouput section.if you guide me by providing sample code that will help me alot.

Comment: @Raju Komaturi, see Zengr's answer. Just change return p1.getPoints().compareTo(p2.getPoints()) to return Math.abs(p1.getPoints() - p2.getPoints()); This will compare players based on the point differences between the 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) with your `player` class (please use "Player", uppercase first letter for classes, otherwise it's confusing):

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player>
{


....


    public int compareTo(Player other)
    {
        if (this.points == other.points)
            return 0;
        if (this.points > other.points)
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Then you can sort the `List` using `Collections.sort(players);`

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for all your answers,But here i dont need sorting order of points.I want a final result to display the players with smallest difference in their points